# Font changes to Times New Roman when pasting into MS Word, depending on markup used

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, ms-word

Let's consider this simple table markup with Bootstrap's `table` class

```
<div>
  <div>
   <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Some row</th>
        <td>Some value</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
   <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Some row</th>
        <td>Some value</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

See it at [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/fracz/c8qvwDhf29).

When you select both tables and paste them into MS Word, the font of the text is *Times New Roman*:

[image: Times new roman font]

However, when I remove the table-wrapping divs (see [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/DuYhig2Ehn)), select them both and copy paste to MS Word, it is pasted as *Helvetica*.

[image: Helvetica font]

Why? I don't see any differences in its CSS styling.

Comment: As you said there's nothing in your CSS that refers to Times New Roman (or even a serif font for that matter). Are you sure you didn't use an advanced paste option that adapts to the current styles of your Word document?

Comment: Just Ctrl+C & Ctrl+V in both cases.

Comment: how are you doing your selecting?

Comment: Ctrl+A & Ctrl+C & Alt+Tab & Ctrl+V